# truncate string in perl into substring with trailing elipses

Tags: perl, substring

I'm trying to truncate a string in a select input option using perl if it is longer than a set value, though i can't get it to work correctly.

```
    my $value = defined $option->{value} ? $option->{value} : '';
    my $maxValueLength = 50;

    if ($value.length > $maxValueLength) {
        $value = substr $value, 0, $maxValueLength + '...';
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several syntax errors. Turn on `use strict` and `use warnings` if you don't have it, and then read the error messages it tells you about. This is a bit tricky because of Perl's very complex syntax (see also [Damian Conway's keynote from the 2020 Perl and Raku Conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVnmYzJfy5s)), but it boils down to these:

1. *Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at line 7*
2. *Argument "..." isn't numeric in addition (+) at line 8*

I've used the following adaption of your code to produce these

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $value          = '1234567890' x 10;
my $maxValueLength = 50;

if ( $value.length > $maxValueLength ) {
    $value = substr $value, 0, $maxValueLength + '...';
}

print $value;
```

Now let's see what they mean.

1. The `.` operator in Perl is a concatenation. You cannot use it to call methods, and `length` is not a method on a string. Perl thinks you are using the [built-in `length`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) (a function, not a method) without an argument, which makes it default to `$_`. Most built-ins do this, to make one-liners shorter. But `$_` is not defined. Now the `.` tries to concatenate the length of `undef` to `$value`. And using `undef` in a string operation leads to this warning.

   The correct way of doing this is `length $value` (or with parentheses if you prefer them, `length($value)`).
2. The `+` operator is not concatenation (we just learned that the `.` is). It's a numerical addition. Perl is pretty good at converting between strings and numbers as there aren't really any types, so saying `1 + "5"` would give you `6` without problems, but it cannot do that for a couple of dots in a string. Hence it complains about a non-number value in an addition.

   You want the substring with a given length, and then you want to attach the three dots. Because of associativity (or *stickyness*) of operators you will need to use parentheses `()` for your `substr` call.

   ```perl
   $value = substr($value, 0, $maxValueLength) . '...';
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is regex

```
$string =~ s/.{$maxLength}\K.*/.../;
```

It matches any character (`.`) given number of times (`{N}`, here `$maxLength`), what is the first `$maxLength` characters in `$string`; then `\K` makes it "forget" all previous matches so those won't get replaced later. The rest of the string that is matched is then replaced by `...`

See [Lookaround assertions in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions) for `\K`.

This does start the regex engine for a simple task but it doesn't need any conditionals -- if the string is shorter than the maximum length the regex won't match and nothing happens.

Comment: To get the OP's required functionality, the replacement string would need to be '`...`' and not the empty string.

Comment: @Silvar Indeed -- thank you, fixed.  (I must've been distracted by the focus on introducing a typical usage -- it's crystal clear in the question, title, and code!)

Answer (score 0):

To find a length of the string use `length(STRING)`

---

Here is the code snippet how you can modify the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
say "length of original string is:".length($string);

my $value = defined $string ? $string : '';
my $maxValueLength = 50;

if (length($value) > $maxValueLength) {
    $value = substr $value, 0, $maxValueLength;
    say "value:$value";
    say "value's length:".length($value);
}
```

**Output:**

```
length of original string is:80
value:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
value's length:50
```